# I can only get either the back or front speakers to play on my computer

Tags: windows-8, speakers

I just got new speakers, and I can't get them to work properly. My sound card has a blue, green and pink port. The wires from my speakers are black and green. If I plug one or the other into my headphones jack either the front or back speakers will play. I can't get them both to play at the same time as the sound card seems to be doing nothing.

Comment: Those jacks aren't front and back speakers.  The front jack is for headphones and inserting the headphone plug disables the speakers.

Comment: That didn't help, and I also don't really understand what you mean. As long as I have one of the two wires plugged into the headphone jack, either the front or back speakers will play. I've tried plugging both wires into all the different colored ports and they don't do anything.

Comment: Do you have an additional (not the motherboard), sound card?  Does it have separate jacks for front (L+R), rear (L+R), and something else (center? subwoofer?)?  That will be independent of the jacks connected to the motherboard, which typically has a speakers (L+R) jack in the rear, and a headphone jack in the front of the case.  Describe the wires from your speakers (what are black and green?  Is each one a 3-way plug for L+R; one for the front speakers and one for the rear?  Plugging anything into the headphone jack will disconnect the speaker jack from the motherboard at the back.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by front and back speakers.  Are you referring to the jacks on the computer case (front and back), or surround sound (pairs of front and back speakers)?  If you have a separate sound card to output surround sound, that will be totally separate from the system jacks and you would have to use those jacks for the different sound channels.

Comment: Green is stereo left & right, black is rear surround left & right. If your card isn't capable of 5.1 surround, it won't have a black port. Green/pink/blue would be stereo/microphone/line-in & no amount of messing with it will add the other channels. The ports on the front & rear of a computer are not meant to be used together. On the front will be mic & headphones, which run from a different header on the motherboard. Plugging in headphones will often [but not always] be set to mute the rear L/R outputs. See http://www.infoaboutcomputer.com/2010/04/computer-sound-card-color-codes.html

Comment: In short, you need a higher-spec soundcard to actually get 4.0 sound - or fake it as dual stereo by splicing the wiring together [at your own risk]

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your computer to enable both sound ports (front and back) if it is possible for your hardware. Sometimes it is possible to do so within the hardware page in your Control Panel in Windows (inside the sound devices page) or by entering the very driver application to your audio card.

Comment: I suspect that won't help in this case.  It sounds like the OP is describing surround sound (front and back speakers; at least four sound channels).  The front jack is a headphone jack that carries the same signal as the speaker jack.  You can sometimes disable the lockout switch so the same signal is live at both jacks, but that will provide the same two channels to both.

Comment: I wouldn't hold high hopes for a consumer I/O of a software/hardware bypass on the 2 headers keeping phase-coherence anyway, so it's likely to sound weird even if achievable.